# Stuck on First Order Logic (Formal Proofs)

Tags: first-order-logic

So I'm stuck with this formal proof problem. This is what I have so far. If it's unclear what I written below here's the link for a more clearer picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAZ7u.jpg

I'm really not sure if what I did is correct so far, I think I may be missing some things. I just need guidance in how to reach the goal. Please help me. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I don't know much about formal logic as you've introduced it, but if it makes sense to type it using MathJax/LaTeX, you should do that. It will get far more attention and help that way.

Comment: From your first contradiction you can only conclude $\operatorname{Dodec}(b)$.  From the second only $\operatorname{Medium}(b)$

Answer (score 0):

Given that your *goal* is $Medium(b) \land Dodec(b)$, you should definitely *not* assume that!  So, get rid of that whole outside subproof.

Also, you should make it a habit to, whenever you start a subproof, to figure out what the last line of the subproof should be, and what you are going to do with the subproof after you close it, all *before* you actually start making further steps inside the subproof. That way, your proof, as well as your thinking itself, keeps much more organized. In fact, had you done this, you would have realized that assuming what you try to prove is never goig to get you anywhere.

Finally, you should look at your premises and your goal and come up with an infomal proof or strategy first before you start makig inferences, otherwise you risk just spinnin your wheels. In this case, if you just think about the premises, and what they mean, it should be pretty straightforward how to get the goal from that: combine the $\neg Small(b)$ from premise 3 with premise 2 to get $Medium(b)$, and combine the $\neg Cube(b)$ from premise 3 with premise 1 to get $Dodec(b)$ and then jus conjunct those two statements to get your goal.

In both cases, you have to follow the Disjunctive Syllogism pattern: this is not a direct rule in Fitch, but the Disjunctive Syllogism pattern of $P \lor Q$, $\neg P$, therefore $Q$ should be in the book, and something you should memorize if you want to get good at these proofs, since this pattern comes up over and over. Indeed, you do this twice in your proof, so here is the general pattern:

1. $P \lor Q$
2. $\neg P$
3. $\qquad P$ Assumption
4. $\qquad \bot$ $\bot$ Intro 2,3
5. $\qquad Q$ $\bot$ Elim 4 (end of first subproof)
6. $\qquad Q$ Assumption (start and end of second subproof)
7. $Q$ $\quad \lor$ Elim 1,3-5,6-6

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice! Sorry, my professor doesn't teach very well so I need to take baby steps to learn this. Okay so based on what you said for P v Q, ¬P, therefore Q, does this meant that the first subproof would be Small(b) ∨ Medium(b) then ¬Small(b) to get Medium(b)? If this is the correct format then what would the rule be? Sorry for all the questions, I really want to learn this & really understand it so I can do good on the final.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I will add the general pattern of Disjunctive Syllogism to my answer.

Comment: On line 4 you assume what you already know to be true on line 2, and similarly on line 7 you assume what you already know to be true on line 1. It makes little sense to assume what you already know, so no, don't start these two subproofs.

Comment: @ashley hey, gotta go, but if you want to do well on the final, do the following two things: first, make a sheet with all the rules. I assume you are using LPL, which has all the rules as an appendix, but that is still 3 pages long and not very accessible. You need to see them on just 1 sheet in front of you while you are doing thse proofs, and after a while you should know them by heart. Second, you need to make a sheet with common patterns, like this Disjunctive Syllogism, but also DeMorgan (especially the on that goes from $\neg(P \lor Q)$ to $\neg P \land \neg Q$), Modus Tollens, and more.